# How do I correctly parse a JSON string using Newtonsoft.json to an object in C#?

Tags: c#, json

I'm creating a little system to let me see who is in my chat on Twitch using their JSON API. However, while I successfully got the information, I can't figure out how to parse it correctly.

This is the string that is being produced:

```
{
  "_links": {},
  "chatter_count": 1,
  "chatters": {
    "moderators": [
      "teonnyn"
    ],
    "staff": [],
    "admins": [],
    "global_mods": [],
    "viewers": []
  }
}
```

This is the object I created to deserialize it to, but I have no idea for sure if it's exactly correct:

```
public class users
{
    public string[] links;
    public int chatter_count;
    public string[] moderators;
    public string[] staff;
    public string[] admins;
    public string[] global_mods;
    public string[] viewers;
}
```

I'm using Newtonsoft.JSON to parse it - which would be the correct way to push the string to the "users" object?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio do you have? I ask because Visual Studio 2015 has a "Paste JSON as classes" under "Paste Special" on the "Edit" menu.

Comment: Also, have you seen this site? http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: just take a look at their examples : http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

Comment: I don't understand thr downvotes. The question seems legitimate, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the C# class you have doesn't really correlate correctly to the JSON:

1. Your `links` member doesn't match the name `_links` in JSON.
2. `_links` is defined as an array, but should be an object - it's `{}` in JSON, not `[]`.
3. Likewise `chatters`, which should be a custom class as well.

Starting with Visual Studio 2013 Update 2, you can generate a C# class from a JSON sample. This is what it generated for your JSON:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public _Links _links { get; set; }
    public int chatter_count { get; set; }
    public Chatters chatters { get; set; }
}

public class _Links
{
}

public class Chatters
{
    public string[] moderators { get; set; }
    public object[] staff { get; set; }
    public object[] admins { get; set; }
    public object[] global_mods { get; set; }
    public object[] viewers { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, it maps `moderators` properly to a `string[]` but gets a bit confused and uses `object[]` for the rest, because the snippet contains to data for it to base the type on.

If you can get a JSON sample with more data - ideally, with every field being present and having representative data - you'll get the best mapping.

Also, you should change `Rootobject` to your own class name, of course. `User` or `TwitchUser` should do it.

Once you have a class that corresponds correctly to your JSON, using JSON.NET to parse it is very simple:

```
Rootobject yourData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(inputJsonString);
```

And you're done.